# Is there a less costly option than gsutil rsync for backup to cloud storage?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

We are currently utilizing the new coldline storage to backup files off site, the storage part is super cost effective. We are using gsutil rsync once a day to make sure our coldline storage is up to date.

The problem is that using gsutil rsync creates a massive number of class A requests, which are quite expensive. In this case it would be at least 5x the amount of the coldline storage making it no longer a good deal.

Are we going to have to custom code a custom solution to avoid these charges, is there a better option for this type of back, or is there some way get rsync to not generate so many requests?

Comment: Which class A requests are you seeing? storage.objects.list ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to get a breakdown of what type of request. I discovered the requests in the billing sectoin. Even if it was a class B request the sheer volume would make it expensive. The only thing in the free tier is delete.

Comment: As jterrace alluded to, gsutil rsync makes object listing operations each time you run it. Since that listing interface retrieves up to 1000 objects with each call (passing a pagination token to get the next 1000 objects), if you have a large number of objects in your bucket it will require many calls just to list the bucket and determine that everything is up to date. How many objects do you have, and how many class A operations are you seeing?

Comment: I have this problem too. Running an rsync job every 4 hours on a bucket that contains 30k objects, I racked up 1200000 class A operations in 6 days... and no objects in the bucket needed to be updated. 

At USD$.10 for 10k operations, it costs me 30 cents each time I do an rsync, regardless of if anything gets updated.

Why does rsync have to do a separate class A operation for each file in the set?

But I don't see any prices per byte for upload, so I wonder if I zipped all 30k objects into a single file and simply copied over a 400gig file if it would only cost me a single operation?

Comment: Even better: Since I know the transfer is single direction from a single computer (from my NAS to Google cloud), I can write a script to check the timestamps and blindly copy them over. Then I only get charged an operation per modified file, which on my dataset happens rarely.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is one pricing trick you can use if the expense is from the `storage.objects.list` operation. From the [GCS operations pricing page](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#operations-pricing): "When an operation applies to a bucket, such as listing the objects in a bucket, the default storage class set for that bucket determines the operation cost. So the trick is:

- Set the bucket's default storage class to STANDARD
- On upload, set the object's storage class to ARCHIVE (using `gsutil cp -s ARCHIVE`, or by setting the appropriate option on the upload requesting using the API).

As far as I understand: this now means you will be charged at the STANDARD rate for listing the bucket ($0.005/10k operations instead of $0.050/10k operations).

The one challenge is that `gsutil rsync` does not support the `-s ARCHIVE` flag that is supported by `gsutil cp`, so you won't be able to use it. You might want to look at other tools, like possibly [rclone](https://rclone.org/).

Comment: NB! The question was about rsync and rsync does not have -s option. Ah, was mentioned also there at the bottom.

Comment: You can rsync, which will create objects with the default storage class and configure the destination bucket to change each objects storage class e.g. after 3 days. Example: https://dpron.com/gcs-archive-backups/